# Can we exchange the order of directional derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:A \subset \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^n$ be $C_2$, $Df_u(a) = f'(a;u)$ the directional derivative of $f$ at $a$ along $u$. I am trying to show that $D_{u_1}D_{u_2}f=D_{u_2}D_{u_1}f$.

I start with checking the LHS, $D_{u_1}D_{u_2}f(a) = D_{u_1}Df(a)(u_2) = (Df(Df(a)(u_2))(u_1)$. Then what? How do I make use of the fact that we can exchange the order of the partial derivatives.

Comment: Hint: $Df_u(a)=\nabla f(a)\cdot u$

Comment: Yes, you can exchange order of differentiation when $f \in C_2$. You can find a proof in standard textbook (say Ch.12 Multivariable Differential Calculus in  book "Mathematical Analysis" by Apostol).

Comment: Yes but I am actually looking for a more general case(say in a normed vector space), which involves some sort of operational calculation using the notation given in the question, do you have any reference on that? @achillehui

Comment: @koch  For finite dimensional vector space, all norm are equivalent. I don't see any real need to go more general. I'm not familiar with infinite dimension vector space. In short, I've no idea ;-p